# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. Navigation View

Tags: android

I have trouble with my code... How can I fixed it? I have already tried all the solutions found on stack...

```
05-29 21:42:48.643 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2-1/lib/x86_64
05-29 21:42:48.802 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2-1/lib/x86_64
05-29 21:42:49.001 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-29 21:42:49.764 3056-3092/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                                 [ 05-29 21:42:49.783  3056: 3056 D/         ]
                                                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f7b62cdcbc0, tid 3056


                                                                                 [ 05-29 21:42:49.825  3056: 3092 D/         ]
                                                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f7b5f3be100, tid 3092
05-29 21:42:49.843 3056-3092/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-29 21:42:58.974 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
05-29 21:42:59.935 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-29 21:43:05.339 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 323 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-29 21:43:10.926 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 334 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-29 21:43:16.455 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 330 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-29 21:43:22.089 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 337 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-29 21:43:40.596 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 308 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-29 21:43:41.551 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-29 21:43:46.950 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 323 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-29 21:43:52.410 3056-3056/com.zakrzewskibartlomiej.cv2016v2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 326 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_material"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_above="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/profile_image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="mymail@ail.com"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I dont know why this is happening. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please post your stack trace and layout XML in the question. Please do not link to them off-site.

Comment: Clean your project and retry once. XML and import looks correct though.

Comment: post you xml code....................!!!

Comment: The problem is with the `CircleImageView` you have in the `nav_header_main` header layout for the `NavigationView`.

Comment: updated this file, what can I do to fix this?  @MikeM.

Comment: Dunno. Your stack trace doesn't specify why the inflation is failing. You'll have to debug.

Comment: @MikeM. allright, now I dont have errors - updated the post